# How to get this line plot to show up properly using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have these data structures:

```
  X axis values:
 delta_Array = np.array([1000,2000,3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000])

  Y Axis values
   error_matrix = 
 [[ 24.22468454  24.22570421  24.22589308  24.22595919  24.22598979
    24.22600641  24.22601644  24.22602294  24.2260274   24.22603059]
  [ 28.54275713  28.54503017  28.54545119  28.54559855  28.54566676
    28.54570381  28.54572615  28.54574065  28.5457506   28.54575771]]
```

How do I plot them as a line plot using matplotlib and python

This code I came up with renders a flat line as follows
     figure(3)
     i = 0

```
 for i in range(error_matrix.shape[0]):
  plot(delta_Array, error_matrix[i,:])

 title('errors')
 xlabel('deltas')
 ylabel('errors')
 grid()
 show()
```

The problem here looks like is scaling of the axes. But im not sure how to fix it. Any ideas, suggestions how to get the curvature showing up properly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ax.twinx` to create twin axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta_Array = np.array([1000,2000,3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000])

error_matrix = np.array(
    [[ 24.22468454, 24.22570421, 24.22589308, 24.22595919, 24.22598979, 24.22600641, 24.22601644, 24.22602294, 24.2260274, 24.22603059],
     [ 28.54275713, 28.54503017, 28.54545119, 28.54559855, 28.54566676, 28.54570381, 28.54572615, 28.54574065, 28.5457506, 28.54575771]])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = []
ax.append(fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1))
ax.append(ax[0].twinx())
colors = ('red', 'blue')

for i,c in zip(range(error_matrix.shape[0]), colors):
    ax[i].plot(delta_Array, error_matrix[i,:], color = c)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

The red line corresponds to `error_matrix[0, :]`, the blue with `error_matrix[1, :]`.

Another possibility is to plot the ratio `error_matrix[0, :]/error_matrix[1, :]`.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib is showing you the right thing. If you want both curves on the same y scale, then they will be flat because their difference is much larger than the variation in each. If you don't mind different y scales, then do as unutbu suggested.

If you want to compare the rate of change between the functions, then I'd suggest normalising by the highest value in each:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(delta_Array, error_matrix[0] / np.max(error_matrix[0]), 'b-')
plt.plot(delta_Array, error_matrix[1] / np.max(error_matrix[1]), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image: functions]

And by the way, you don't need to be explicit in the dimensions of your 2D array. When you use `error_matrix[i,:]`, it is the same as `error_matrix[i]`.